# How to unhide the UITabbarcontroller when hidden by "setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed" in previous viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have to hide the tabbar for some of the view and put the button instead of that tabbar i used setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed method to hide that but when i m trying to unhide that tababar by same method it fails to do that.

while hiding methods is
[obj_gift_page setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

while Unhiding method is
[obj_gift_page setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unhide the tabbar by just putting:

```
[obj_gift_page setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
```

It'll stay in hidden state untill you pop the pushed view controller from the navigation stack.

Comment: Is there another method to hide it. by which i can unhide it again.

Comment: nope, using this you can't. In my knowledge there is no alternate solutions. I'll check it also, and update my answer if I find any solutions.